# C++ Winsock client will not receive data from server, but with Putty client it works

Tags: c++, winsock, winsock2

I need to send some data to a device. For that, I'm trying to use a WinSock socket client. The connection in principal works, but I get no data back, only an `ACK`. I tried this same test with a Putty client, there I was receiving data. I was looking with Wireshark and I saw that my WinSock client is sending a `FIN` after transmitting the data. That is not the case with Putty. I know the `FIN` will be sent because of `shutdown(SD_SEND)`, but how can I handle this in another way? You can see this in the Pictures below.

Wireshark for WinSock:

[image: Wireshark for WinSock]

Wireshark for Putty:

[image: Wireshark for Putty]

Here is my client code:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib, Mswsock.lib, and Advapi32.lib
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "AdvApi32.lib")


#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define DEFAULT_PORT "8000"
#define DEFAULT_IP "127.0.0.1"

//int __cdecl main(int argc, char** argv)
int __cdecl main()
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    struct addrinfo* result = NULL,
        * ptr = NULL,
        hints;
    const char* sendbuf = "M:UA 111111 SEP1,00000";
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int iResult;
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

    // Validate the parameters
   // if (argc != 2) {
   //     printf("usage: %s server-name\n", argv[0]);
   //     return 1;
   // }

    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    // Resolve the server address and port
   // iResult = getaddrinfo(argv[1], DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    iResult = getaddrinfo(DEFAULT_IP, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);

    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Attempt to connect to an address until one succeeds
    for (ptr = result; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->ai_next) {

        // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
        ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype,
            ptr->ai_protocol);
        if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        // Connect to server.
        iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            closesocket(ConnectSocket);
            ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Unable to connect to server!\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Send an initial buffer
    iResult = send(ConnectSocket, sendbuf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0);
   
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Bytes Sent: %ld\n", iResult);
    

    // shutdown the connection since no more data will be sent
    iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
   
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Receive until the peer closes the connection
    do {

        iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        if (iResult > 0)
            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
        else if (iResult == 0)
            printf("Connection closed\n");
        else
            printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

    } while (iResult > 0);

    // cleanup
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you think that's because of your client is sending FIN, call shutdown right before closesocket. When that's not the source of the problem, try to compare the data sent by putty and your client in wireshark. Anyway without pcaps of both applications connections or the source of the server we can only guess.

Answer (score 0):

Putty is sending 2 extra bytes after each text. Presumably a CRLF line ending.  Your Winsock code is not sending those 2 bytes.  Chances are, the server is expecting a line break to arrive before sending data back to the client.

Try changing this:

`const char* sendbuf = "M:UA 111111 SEP1,00000";`

To this:

`const char* sendbuf = "M:UA 111111 SEP1,00000\r\n";`

And no, Putty is not sending a `FIN`, because it is a user-controlled terminal, and the user (you) hasn't indicated to it that further text will not be entered, so it just sits there waiting for more text to send.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the fast respond. I tried this, but it will not work. Also I have looked into Wireshark for the Putty package, there were not two extra Bytes on the end.